# Additional brick veneer to existing construction

Tags: brick, masonry

I am looking at a home that is a 2 story colonial. The first 10 feet or so from the ground is brick veneer (one row thick), and the upper story is vinyl. The vinyl is looking pretty bad. Is it possible, that since the foundation is obviously there for the first story brick, that I could remove the siding, and just continue the brick to the top?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a typical stepped foundation should carry two stories of brick just fine. That said, I'm looking at your project through a few words on the internet. Photos would move us in a more confident direction.